# Why I don't need to authenticate the user before i can execute query in CSOM example

Tags: sharepoint

I am going thru the examples here which shows how to perform basic operations with the SharePoint 2013 .NET Framework client object model (CSOM).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx
My question is why I don't need to authenticate the user before i can execute query in CSOM

For example

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// The SharePoint web at the URL.
Web web = context.Web; 

// We want to retrieve the web's properties.
context.Load(web); 

// Execute the query to the server.
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

// Now, the web's properties are available and we could display 
// web properties, such as title. 
label1.Text = web.Title;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do this cause it will use the current logged in user. Otherwise you have to impersonate the user first.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://server/");
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
// Some Cording
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: If I want to run the above sharepoint client example, what kind of Visual studio C# project i should create? I create an 'App for sharepoint' project but it generates a lot of js and html code for me. I just want a C# project to execute query to Sharepoint site.

Comment: Thank you @STORM. I try your solution. But I got a '403 Forbidden' exception. I have double check the credentials by going to 'http://server/site/myname' in browser, and i am able to login using {user}@{domain}  and with the password {password}.